# DirectShow Graph::RenderFile --> VFW_E_NOT_FOUND with rebuilt project

Tags: c++, directshow

After I have reinstalled VC++ 2008 during my yearly cleanup on my PC, my multimedia project that compiled and worked without a problem, seems to produce a strange error:

The application basically is a media player and uses DirectShow. I already retried it with the standard example of MSDN ["HOW TO PLAY A FILE"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd389098%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and appearently the error happens at this line:

```
hr = pGraph->RenderFile(L"C:\\TEST.avi");
```

hr (HRESULT) returns VFW_E_NOT_FOUND and I have no idea why because the example file IS there, I already change the location AND the example file but anyway it keeps failing.

Could this error result from a damaged file or a wrong file version or am I just too dumb to find the error? I reinstalled every application I have had on the PC before reinstalling Windows, EXCEPT Visual Studio C++ 2010.

My configuration:

Windows 7 Ultimate x64 SP1

VC++ 2008 Express

Windows 7 SDK amd64 installed

DirectX SDK June 2010 installed

Comment: maybe a missing codec in your brand new OS? Can you play the same file win wmplayer?

Comment: can play it with Windows MP and even build the Graph with GraphEdit...don't know what hates me here...

Comment: Make sure that you have your codecs available for X86 and X64 CPU architectures, or try building your project as 32 bits, (wmplayer is 32 bits only if I remember correctly).

Comment: GRRRR.....I want an "show anything" button for windows.... You know what was the problem?? I did not set the folder options properly (as is was used to --> show ALL extensions) and added -- as usual -- the AVI extension renaming the file to "Test.avi.avi", god I am such an idiot!!

Answer (score 0):

Question "answered", look for the comment below the question...
In short:

Folder options --> Hide known extensions checkbox ticked.
Renamed File as "TEST.avi" results in real name: TEST.avi.avi

(TEST.avi == Test.avi.avi) == FALSE --> me.idiot = true;

Actually, this question could be deleted (no real coding issue)!

Comment: You have to admit the API was helpful and provided you with a relevant error code :)

Answer (score 0):

Just for people like me who will try to find an answer.

In my case the path was right. But I still was getting the same error `VFW_E_NOT_FOUND`.
I tried to open a video file with media player and I got an error too.
The problem was in missing codecs.

The **solution** is to install [K-Lite Codec Pack](https://www.codecguide.com/download_kl.htm).
And the error disappeared.